# Why doesn't VB.NET give the same "field initializer can't reference non-static member" warnings as C#?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I've been bitten several times by writing VB.NET code like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private DoesntWork As New List(Of TextBox)({TextBox1, TextBox2})
    Private Works As List(Of TextBox)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Works = New List(Of TextBox)({TextBox3, TextBox4})
    End Sub
End Class
```

where `DoesntWork` is initialized to a list with two members, both of which are `Nothing` even though the initializer says they should be TextBox1 and TextBox2 (which are, of course, controls on the form).

The equivalent C# code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<TextBox> DoesntWork = new List<TextBox>(){textBox1, textBox2};
    private List<TextBox> Works;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Works = new List<TextBox>(){textBox3, textBox4};
    }
}
```

gives the error

> Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.textBox1'

Why doesn't the VB compiler give the same error? It instead crashes at runtime, which is obviously worse.

Comment: Because VB allows you to initialize a field to a non-static field, method, or property.  The fact that the textboxes are nothing is another issue.

Comment: Just another case of VB's lenient compiler in action.  It has bitten many people many times.

Comment: This is subjective.  It isn't necessarily an error so outlawing it in the language is a choice.  And the C# and VB.NET teams make different choices, kinda the point of having two languages.  The `As New` syntax is pretty popular in VB.NET, C# doesn't have it.  A warning would have been nice, perhaps.  But you'll have to ask the VB.NET team, nothing we can do about it.

Comment: @Hans - The `As New` syntax doesn't really matter, the same thing still happens when you do `As List(Of TextBox) = New List(Of TextBox)({TextBox1, TextBox2})`.

Comment: Sure, and that's possible in C# as well.  Yet they decided to still outlaw such a field initializer.  Without the equivalent of As New in C# there are more accidents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kvermeer, it's "simple". The VB Class initializes the variables as the "New()" method is called. In that matter, when the "New()" method creates the class, it sets it's value as "{TextBox1, TextBox2}", but the "InitializeComponents()" methods wasn't yet called, so "TextBox1" and "TextBox2" are still NOTHING.

On The class you wrote:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private DoesntWork As New List(Of TextBox)({TextBox1, TextBox2})
    Private Works As List(Of TextBox)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Works = New List(Of TextBox)({TextBox3, TextBox4})
    End Sub
End Class
```

The sequence followed by the program is:

1. Set "DoesntWork" as a new list os TextBoxes composed by the value of
   TextBox1 and TextBox2 (but they are not initialized yet, so they're
   both NOTHING).
2. Since "works" doesn't have a initial value, it's not
   set.
3. Then call "InitializeComponent()" method (wrote on the
   "Form1.Designer.vb" file (that initializes TextBox1 and TextBox2,
   but not the list of "doesntwork", because it was initialized already
   with 2 NOTHING references).
4. Set the "Works" variable.
5. End the "New()" method.

Comment: Thanks! I had assumed that the `New()` method (and therefore also `InitializeComponent()` would be called before the fields were initialized.  This explains the behavior!

Comment: @kvermeer you can set a breakpoint in Sub New and see that is not the case.  Before the first line of Sub New code executes, all the code which initializes variables is run `Private foo As String = ""` as well as code that creates object instances `Private DoesntWork As New List(Of ...`.  **Then** the first line of code in Sub New runs.  its the same for Classes as Forms (because forms are classes)